# ListView(large data set-cursor) With SectionIndexer working not properly

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursor

Nearly I have 33000 rows with 5 columns in cursor. 
   While loading this cursor with custom cursor adapter showing the message as:

```
**E/CursorWindow(32613): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 11, freeSpace() = 10, numRows = 15583
     E/CursorWindow(32613): not growing since there are already 15583 row(s), max size 1048576
     E/Cursor(32613): Failed allocating 11 bytes for text/blob at 15582,0
     D/Cursor(32613): finish_program_and_get_row_count row 19920**
```

As per the cursor documentation,don't use large data sets.

Even that, I have used large data set.

Where i strucked is,  if i directly goes to first index to 
 some last indexes, It works but,scrolling up of listview is strucked. 
 While going to first index to some last indexes, It shows message as

**skip_rows rows numberOfRows(number)**

So,please any one guide me to correct way.

Thanks In Advance